# SBT: view class file summary during compilation?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, playframework-2.0, sbt, summary

Trying to see exactly what source files are being compiled during full & incremental builds.

As it stands I see a summary a la "X number of Scala and Y number of Java files" being compiled, which is great, but *exactly which* files are being compiled?

```
set logLevel in Global := Level.Debug
```

does nothing useful (that I can see)

```
set scalacOptions in Compile += "-print"
```

is more helpful, it prints out the internet...I mean, tons of generated code, which does contain the class names, just not so easy to sift through.

Basically looking to get a summary of files being compiled.

Perhaps there's a non-verbose option to the above scalac flag?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any options that would permit that, but it would probably be the simplest compiler plugin you could write (http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140).

Answer (score 2):

Try `-verbose`. This shows which classes are being parsed,

```
[ERROR] [parsing Tapnon.scala]
[ERROR] [parsing Tapnonics.scala]
[ERROR] [parsing package.scala]
[ERROR] [parsing EvenlyScorer.scala]
```